# Replacing preg_replace (with deprecated /e parameter) to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

While working with some legacy code, I have came across 2 `preg_replace` functions with now deprecated `/e` parameter. PHP suggest to replace it with `preg_replace_callback`.

These are the functions:

- First:

  ```
  $content = preg_replace("/(\{([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\})/e", null, $content);
  ```

  From what I understand, `/e` is safe to remove from this function?
- Second:

  ```
  $text = preg_replace(
      "/<(h[2])>(.+)<\/(h[2])>/Uie",
      "'<\\1 id=\"'.createIdByText('\\2').'\">'.stripslashes('\\2').'</\\1>'",
      $text
  );
  ```

Can anyone help me fixing these or converting to preg_replace_callback so they don't throw a deprecation warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you can indeed just remove the `e`. For the second case:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback(
    "/<h2>(.+)<\/h2>/Ui",
    function($matches) {
        return '<h2 id="' . createIdByText($matches[1]) . '">' . $matches[1] . '</h2>';
    },
    $text
);
```

I took the freedom to simplify the regular expression a bit. The `stripslashes` call is no longer necessary, as it was only there to work around the automatic `addslashes` call that `/e` uses.

Comment: Thank you, I need a few more minutes to test it and will mark it as solved.

Comment: p.s. since I can't suggest edit of only 1 character, there is a comma missing after fuinction close bracket. You might want to edit that.